# Vulkan, do I need and when free memory from VK_* structures

Tags: memory, memory-management, vulkan

stupid question, sorry

**first question**

```
void init_something(...){
    VkTypeSomething data[100];
    VkResourceStruct resource={... .pointer_data=data};
    VkCreateSomething(... , resource); //isit safe? resource[] is not lost?
}

void vk_clean(...){
    VkDestroySomething_that_use_resource(...);
    // free resource?
}
```

**second question**

same code, changes `VkTypeSomething *data;` and `data=malloc(...);` (no free in function)

when I need to free that data if I malloc it, and do I need to free it

Vulkan pages tell that "structures are destroyed on VkDestroy... call" and "VkDestroy... must have valid poiinters in structures on call" so there no way to free it before call (I know it can not work like this)

so there no way to get pointer inside structure that was created somewhere... do I need save all my created pointers and free them my self, after VkDestroy?

look like I understand, but still not sure
as I understand its "VkCreate... use setup-data only once" and **it safe to delete everything after call  VkCreate... its true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulkan **handles** are created by `vkCreate*`, and destroyed by `vkDestroy*`. They have nothing to do with any structures. I am not sure what your custom `VkCreate*` is or does, so that is outside of the scope of Vulkan.

You are the owner of all the **struct**s. Generally, Vulkan only borrows them for the duration of a function call (Vulkan spec):

> The ownership of application-owned memory is immediately acquired by any Vulkan command it is passed into. Ownership of such memory **must** be released back to the application at the end of the duration of the command, so that the application **can** alter or free this memory as soon as all the commands that acquired it have returned.

Comment: "Vulkan only borrows them for the duration of a function call (Vulkan spec):" - that what I need to know, thanks